# Check two list of values statistically significantly different from each other

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, number-comparison

So I have two lists.

**l_2014=[22,27,58,62,75,122]**

**l_2015=[23,25,60,62,74,124]**

Each number inside a list represents the average travel time of a road segment for a year. l_2014 for the year 2014, and l_2015 for the year 2015.

I also have a weight for the usage of these segments.

### W=[100,200,150,100,100,70]

My question is how to decide whether the travel time is significantly different from each other collectively. i.e. the network's travel time significantly change from the year before?

What indicators should I use? Can I simply average/weighted average them to see the mean difference?

Thanks!